# WebdriverIO chromedriver preferences ignored

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to setup preferences for Chrome in WebdriverIO, but it seems like they are being ignored by the driver. The preferences I am currently trying to set are these:

```
capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        prefs: {
            'download.prompt_for_download': false,
            'download.directory_upgrade': true,
            'download.default_directory': 'C:/Downloads',
            'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': true
        }
    }
}],
```

I have tried a couple of other preferences to test if it's these particular ones that don't work as well as tried providing the args property to the chromeOptions. Considering the arguments work fine, while none of the preferences I tried did, I've come to the conclusion that the prefs are simply being ignored.

Is anyone aware of the reason why this may be happening?

Comment: Capabilities object looks correct. Some prefs might be wrong or no longer supported by Chrome or chromedriver. What are you trying to achieve?